# System of equations trigonometric in Reals

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Solve in Reals

$$\begin{cases}
\cos x+\cos y=\frac{1}{2} \\ 
\tan x +\tan y=2\\
\text{I tried:}\\ 
\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}+\frac{\sin y}{\cos y}=2\rightarrow \sin x \cos y+\sin y\cos x=2\cos x\cos y\rightarrow \\
\frac{1}{2}[\sin(x-y)+\sin(x+y)]
+\frac{1}{2}[\sin(x+y)-\sin(x-y)]=2\cos x\cos y\\ 
\sin(x-y)+\sin(x+y)+\sin(x+y)-\sin(x-y)=4\cos x\cos y 
\rightarrow\\ 
2\sin(x-y) = 4\cos x\cos y\\
\sin(x-y)=2\cos x\cos y
\rightarrow \sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y=2 \cos x\cos y
\\
\sin x\cos y-\cos x\sin y-2\cos x\cos y=0
\rightarrow \sin x\cos y-\cos x(\sin y+2\cos y)=0???
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Questions posted here should not be phrased in that way. You need to make it clear that there is a question in your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} 
\cos x+\cos y=\tfrac{1}{2} 
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
\tan x +\tan y=2
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Subtracting $(\tan y +1)$ from \eqref{2}
and squaring, we get

\begin{align} 
(\tan x-1)^2
&=
(1-\tan y)^2
,\\
\tan^2x+1-2\tan x
&=
\tan^2y+1-2\tan y
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-2\tan x
&=
\frac{1}{\cos^2y}-2\tan y
\tag{4}\label{4}
.
\end{align}

Substitution of $\tan y=2-\tan x$ into \eqref{4}
and rearrangement
results in

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\cos^2x}
-\frac{1}{\cos^2y}
+4&=4\tan x=4\,\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
\tag{5}\label{5}
.\\
\end{align}

Substitution of $\cos y=\tfrac12-\cos x$ into \eqref{5}
results in

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\cos^2x}
-\frac{1}{(\tfrac12-\cos x)^2}
+4&=4\,\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
\frac{1}{\cos x}
-\frac{\cos x}{(\tfrac12-\cos x)^2}
+4\,\cos x&=4\,\sin x
\tag{7}\label{7}
.
\end{align}

After squaring \eqref{7} we have

\begin{align}
\frac{
(1-4\,\cos x+4\,\cos^2 x-16\,\cos^3 x
+16\,\cos^4 x)^2}{
\cos^2x\,(1-2\,\cos x)^4} 
&= 16\,\sin^2x=16\,(1-\cos^2x)
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

Assuming that $\cos x\ne0$, $1-\cos^2x\ne0$, 
we arrive at equation in $t=\cos x$
\begin{align}
512\,t^8-1024\,t^7+512\,t^6
+128\,t^5-192\,t^4+64\,t^3+8\,t^2-8\,t+1
&=0
\tag{9}\label{9}
.\\
\end{align}

Luckily, \eqref{9} can be factored into
\begin{align}
(32\,t^4-32\,t^3+4\,t-2-\sqrt2)
(32\,t^4-32\,t^3+4\,t-2+\sqrt2)
&=0
\tag{10}\label{10}
,
\end{align}

which has six real roots:
\begin{align}
t_{1}&=\tfrac14+\tfrac14\,\sqrt{3+2\,\sqrt{5+2\,\sqrt2}},\\
t_{2}&=\tfrac14-\tfrac14\,\sqrt{3+2\,\sqrt{5+2\,\sqrt2}},\\
t_{3}&=\tfrac14+\tfrac14\,\sqrt{3+2\,\sqrt{5-2\,\sqrt2}},\\ 
t_{4}&=\tfrac14-\tfrac14\,\sqrt{3+2\,\sqrt{5-2\,\sqrt2}},\\ 
t_{5}&=\tfrac14+\tfrac14\,\sqrt{3-2\,\sqrt{5-2\,\sqrt2}},\\ 
t_{6}&=\tfrac14-\tfrac14\,\sqrt{3-2\,\sqrt{5-2\,\sqrt2}}
.
\end{align}

Equations \eqref{1},\eqref{2} are symmetric in $x,y$,
and indeed,

\begin{align}
t_2&=\tfrac12-t_1
,\\
t_4&=\tfrac12-t_3
,\\
t_6&=\tfrac12-t_5
,
\end{align}

so, basically, we can consider just three of them.

Next,
\begin{align}
\cos x&=t_i,\quad
\cos y=\tfrac12-t_i
,\\
x&=\pm \arccos (t_i)+2\pi\,n,\quad
y=\pm \arccos(\tfrac12-t_i)+2\pi\,m 
,
\end{align}

so we need to check which combinations of the signs 
satisfy \eqref{2}.

And the three suitable pairs of $x,y$ for $n=m=0$
happens to be
\begin{align}
(\arccos t_1,\ -\arccos(\tfrac12-t_i))
&\approx(0.1848292031,\ -2.074837017)
,\\
(-\arccos t_3,\ -\arccos(\tfrac12-t_3))
&\approx(-0.5361638202,\ -1.938715548)
,\\
(-\arccos t_5,\ \arccos(\tfrac12-t_5))
&\approx(-1.258318311,\ 1.377003189)
.
\end{align}